# How to install/enable ftpcopy binary and mysqldump binary on WHM cPanel

Tags: ftp, mysql

I'm running WHM and cPanel and have a script that requires the following

> ftpcopy binary (for Create/Refresh local FTP mirror)
>
> mysqldump binary (for Create local SQL mirror)

And I need to know how to enable/install these 'features' or 'modules' on my server.

The path to both are defined as `/usr/bin/ftpcopy` and `/usr/bin/mysqldump` in the script but I don't know how to check for these.

I have full access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump came along with mysql server.

so, if you have mysql server installed, it's there.

to install ftpcopy, (if you're using centos/rhel/fedora) this should work:

```
yum install ftpcopy
```

to check where it's installed:

```
whereis mysqldump
whereis ftpcopy
```

or

```
which mysqldump
which ftpcopy
```

Comment: I tried yum on my CentOS / cPanel box and it didn't know about ftpcopy.

Comment: i just search on http://rpm.pbone.net and see that ftpcopy only available on ancient distros (fedora3, rh9, etc). and not found on any latest distro. whatever the reason recent distros stop distributing ftpcopy, imho you should also seek for alternatives. try lftp. it have better feature and it's on any latest distro. you could make a simple bash script to translate ftpcopy command to lftp.

Comment: or you could also just download any of the old rpm there and try install it with rpm -i ftpcopy-0.6.7....rpm at your own risk!

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump should already be installed. Instructions for installing ftpcopy are at: http://www.ohse.de/uwe/ftpcopy/install.html